# Swagger interacting with Resteasy not listing content api

Tags: swagger, resteasy

We're trying to have Swagger interact with our resteasy app so that the api will list out on the swagger page.  We're using annotations in the Java resources and not a yaml/json file.  We want the content to be 'dynamic' or come directly from the resource pages.

When we bring up the swagger page, we get the message 'fetching resource list: //10.155.63.136/nodeMgmt'.  When I render the page using firebug, I see that the page itself (index.html) is being 'fed in' to the content.

I think I'm pretty close but am missing one or two small things.  I used the example as a guide to what I did:  https://github.com/mrj365/RestEasy-3.09-Spring-3.2.5-Swagger2.0

Again, the issue is that the content from the resteasy api is not being fed into the swagger ui.  The url in my case is https://10.155.63.92/nodeMgmt/index.html

We're using JBoss 6.4, NO Spring, Resteasy 3.0.7, Swagger jaxrs 1.5.9.

Any help is really appreciated.

Index.html

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        window.swaggerUi = new SwaggerUi({
        url: "/nodeMgmt",
        dom_id: "swagger-ui-container",
        supportedSubmitMethods: ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete'],
        onComplete: function(swaggerApi, swaggerUi){
            log("Loaded SwaggerUI");

            $('pre code').each(function(i, e) {
                hljs.highlightBlock(e)
            });
        },
        onFailure: function(data) {
            log("Unable to Load SwaggerUI");
        },
        docExpansion: "none"
    });
```

web.xml

```
  <!-- Auto scan REST service -->
   <context-param>
      <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
   </context-param>

   <context-param>
      <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
      <param-value>/nodes</param-value>
   </context-param>


  <filter>
    <filter-name>ApiOriginFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.sonus.unity.sonusbaserestservice.utils.ApiOriginFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ApiOriginFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/index.html</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

   <!-- if you are using Spring, Seam or EJB as your component model, remove the ResourceMethodSecurityInterceptor -->
   <context-param>
      <param-name>resteasy.resource.method-interceptors</param-name>
      <param-value>
         org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodSecurityInterceptor
      </param-value>
   </context-param>

   <listener>
      <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
   </listener>

   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
             <init-param>
                <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
                <param-value>com.sonus.ems.nodemgmt.web.NodeMgmtApplication</param-value>
            </init-param>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/nodes/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
```

application.java

```
@ApplicationPath("")
public class NodeMgmtApplication extends SonusBaseRestApplication  {
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(NodeMgmtApplication.class);

    /**
     *  Constructor
     */
    public NodeMgmtApplication() {
        super();

        try {
            //TODO Swagger
            // Used for defining swagger
            BeanConfig beanConfig = new BeanConfig();
            beanConfig.setSchemes(new String[]{"http"});
            beanConfig.setHost("localhost:8080");
            beanConfig.setVersion("1.5.9");
            beanConfig.setBasePath("/nodeMgmt");
            beanConfig.setResourcePackage("com.sonus.ems.nodemgmt.web");
            //beanConfig.setPrettyPrint(true);
            beanConfig.setScan(true);

            addService(new NodeMgmtAuthorizationFilter());
            addService(new NodeMgmtRestService());

            // Swagger
            addService(new ApiListingResource());
            addService(new SwaggerSerializers());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("NodeAdminApplication: Could not instantiate singletons " + e);
        }
    }
```

resource.java

```
@Path("/")
@Api(value = "/", description = "Node operations", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class NodeMgmtRestService {
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(NodeMgmtRestService.class);

    private static final String NODES = "nodes";
    private static final String ID = "id";


    NodeMgmtServiceProvider nodeMgmtServiceProvider = new NodeMgmtServiceProvider();

    Service nodeMgmtService;


    @GET
    @Path("/{version}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @ApiOperation(value = "Get all nodes", notes = "Returns a list of node", response = String.class, responseContainer="List")
    public Response getNodes(
            @ApiParam(value = "Version of api (1.0)", required = true) @PathParam("version") String version,
            @ApiParam(value = "Filter by ", required = true) @QueryParam("filterParam") String filterParam,
            @ApiParam(value = "Filter value ", required = true) @QueryParam("filterValue") String filterValue) {
        List<Node> nodeList = new ArrayList<Node>();
        List<Object> nodeJsonList = new ArrayList<Object>();
        Map<String, List<Object>> nodeJsonMap = new HashMap<String, List<Object>>();
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Map<String, String> responseId = new HashMap<String, String>();
        JsonNodeDao jsonNodeDao = new JsonNodeDao();
```

Swagger API key

```
public class ApiOriginFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
      public void doFilter(
              ServletRequest request, 
              ServletResponse response,
              FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;

        // Add access to the header 
        res.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, PATCH, OPTIONS");
        res.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, api_key, Authorization");
        //res.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Atmosphere-tracking-id, X-Atmosphere-Framework, X-Cache-Date, Content-Type, api_key, Authorization, X-Atmosphere-Transport, x-requested-with, Total-Count, Total-Pages, Error-Message, *");
        //res.addHeader("Access-Control-Request-Headers", "Origin, X-Atmosphere-tracking-id, X-Atmosphere-Framework, X-Cache-Date, Content-Type, api_key, Authorization, X-Atmosphere-Transport, x-requested-with, Total-Count, Total-Pages, Error-Message,  *");

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
      }

      @Override
      public void destroy() {
      }

      @Override
      public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
      }
```